# When to use @ref for child component in Blazor

Tags: razor, blazor

The parent page has two child components and a button.
On page load, the two components should be visible.
The button click should toggle their visibility.

I'm able to achieve the desired output, but would like to understand the best way.

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"    

<button @onclick="ToggleVisibility">Toggle Visibility</button>
<br />
<VisibilityComponent1 ShowComponent=visibilityState></VisibilityComponent1>
<br />
<VisibilityComponent2 @ref="visibilityComponent2"></VisibilityComponent2>

@code
{
    private bool visibilityState = true;
    private VisibilityComponent2 visibilityComponent2;

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        visibilityComponent2.SetVisibility(visibilityState);
    }

    private void ToggleVisibility()
    {
        visibilityState = !visibilityState;
        visibilityComponent2.SetVisibility(visibilityState);
    }
}
```

**VisibilityComponent1.razor**

```
@if (ShowComponent)
{
    <h3>First Component</h3>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowComponent { get; set; }
}
```

**VisibilityComponent2.razor**

```
@if (showComponent)
{
    <h3>Second Component</h3>
}

@code {
    private bool showComponent;

    public void SetVisibility(bool isVisible)
    {
        showComponent = isVisible;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

For `VisibilityComponent1`, I have used the `Parameter` approach and for `VisibilityComponent2`, the `@ref` approach.

#1. I have used `OnAfterRender` to make `VisibilityComponent2` visible. Is this the correct way?
#2. What is the difference between these two approaches. Could you please explain when to use which with any real-time example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #2. What is the difference between these two approaches. Could you please explain when to use which with any real-time example.

When you need to use the component as a variable you'd attach it to an `@ref`. Maybe pass it as a cascading value or call some method on it like `visibilityComponent2.RefreshSomeData()`. In your example you don't **need** to use the component as a variable. In doing so makes the code more complex for no reason. `VisibilityComponent1` would be the way to go here.

> #1. I have used OnAfterRender to make VisibilityComponent2 visible. Is this the correct way?

In your example you pretty much have to do it here because of the `@ref`. It will be null in `OnInitialized` and `OnParametersSet`. When your render mode is `ServerPrerendered` you'll generally want to put javascript and code that you only want to execute once in the `OnAfterRender` on the `firstRender`. If your render mode is `Server` you can get away with doing some things earlier in the life cycle (especially javascript). In `Server` mode each portion of the life cycle is only executed once.

Answer (score 3):

I think the code answers your question:

The `@ref` approach for VisibilityComponent2  is much more complex. Meaning it is also more error-prone. And there isn't any benefit.

VisibilityComponent1 is more streamlined and follows the normal Blazor rendering flow.

On a side note, both approaches only make sense when VisibilityComponent1 or VisibilityComponent2 have some state to maintain. Otherwise, the most efficient solution would be:

```
<button @onclick="ToggleVisibility">Toggle Visibility</button>
<br />
@if(visibilityState)
{
  <VisibilityComponent1></VisibilityComponent1>
  <br />
  <VisibilityComponent2></VisibilityComponent2>
}
```

Comment: I agree with Henk.  Updating a parameter fits with the Blazor component design philosophy.  Personally 1. I only put code in `OnAfterRender` that does JS stuff.  2.  avoid wherever possible making manual `StateHasChanged` calls. ". 3. Avoid where possible using @ref and making parent to child component calls.

Comment: IMHO This approach will not even render VisibilityComponent1 and VisibilityComponent2, and  its a matter of existence for components but not show/hide. To actually show/hide these components, style or class seems better option, any thoughts?

Comment: @SurinderSingh - when the Comp exists it will be rendered. Not exisiting is the efficiency gain.